# How can I run Neural Machine Translation with Attention in Google Colab with a different paired language?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to use a different language pair at the example provided in TernsorFlow website, Google Colab notebook only picks spanish-english
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention.ipynb

I tried changing the link to the esp-eng data that download's from it, but that didn't help

How can I try a different language set, without locally setting-up colab, it did mention at the end on that page, that I can try a different language set.

Answer (score 0):

The final note on using a different dataset refers to [this website](http://www.manythings.org/anki/) which includes tab-delimited files.

You mainly need to change the values in this cell according to the link to the zip file you need.

```
# Download the file
path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'spa-eng.zip', origin='http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/spa-eng.zip',
    extract=True)

path_to_file = os.path.dirname(path_to_zip)+"/spa-eng/spa.txt"
```

You can try other datasets from:

- [OPUS](http://opus.nlpl.eu/)
- [WMT](http://www.statmt.org/wmt19/translation-task.html)

However, in these corpora, the source and target are in two separate files, so you have to adjust the code that extracts pairs, instead of `split('\t')` it should open two files and get the source and target line by line.